# Rails tests don't seem to be loading any classes, NameError: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, minitest

Suddenly whenever I run 'rake test' or 'bundle exe rake test' I get the following error.

```
NameError: uninitialized constant FactoryGirl
```

Before anyone tells me to add `require 'factory_girl'`  to my `test_helper.rb` file, the same updated branch is running the tests without any problem in another computer.

Still I've tried adding `require 'factory_girl'`. Then it raised another error saying `NameError: uninitialized constant Faker`, and so I added `require 'faker'` and there was always something it required, and the tests for this project always worked fine without all those requires.

Info that might be useful:

- Ubuntu 16.10
- Rails 5.1.1
- Ruby 2.3.3 (using rbenv)
- I'm using minitest, not RSPEC

Error bracktrace:

```
** Invoke test (first_time)
** Execute test
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant FactoryGirl
/home/samir/Projects/Tuuris/test/test_helper.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/home/samir/Projects/Tuuris/test/controllers/admin_controller_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:14:in `block in require_files'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:13:in `each'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:13:in `require_files'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:67:in `rake_run'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin/rake:22:in `load'
/home/samir/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => test
```

Any clue?

Comment: Are you using `bundle`? Do you have `factory_girl` in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: Yes, `bundle` runs fine. I do have `factory_girl` , `faker` and other gems in the test group. Like I said, the tests are running fine in another computer. I even removed ruby 2.3.3 using rbenv and installed it again, and doing so, it installed all those gems. Still I got the same error. :/

Comment: Sanity check: Run `bundle exec rspec`

Comment: `bundler: command not found: rspec`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so when I had given up, I found the problem already.

tl;dr : had to remove `RAILS_ENV=development` from `.rbenv-vars`

Complete answer:

Test gems were in a group to run only in the test environment like this:

```
group :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'cpf_faker'
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'minitest-capybara'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem "capybara-webkit"
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'minitest-rails'
end
```

The thing is... I'm using whenever gem to run some tasks every day, but whenever is not able to find which environment it is being run, so I was using RAILS_ENV=development in my `.rbenv-vars` file.

Because of that, even `rake test` was being run on development environment, I don't know why this is allowed to happen though.